# How to create an AngularJS service that is accessible from the default app / custom module

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS (reading docs for a week or so) so bear with me :) I am trying to expose some 3rd party library (JayData) functionality to AngularJS controllers via the DI/service infrastructure.

Creating a service is a straightforward thing, as long as you can manage to create your own module for this, and set ng-app to that module.

```
    var mod = angular.module('myModule', [], function ($provide) {
        $provide.factory('$data', ['$scope', function (sc) {
            return $data;
        }]);
    });

   <html ng-app='myModule'></html>
```

In my case developers will create their own app/startup module, or will use the "default ng app" without specifying an kind of module names like `<html ng-app=""`.

How can I register a service that is globally accessible like the built-in services like $scope or $http?

Comment: Is there something against declaring a dependency on your module in their module definition? That is: `var module = angular.module("TheirThirdPartyModule", ["YourModule"])`? That's the regular way to do these things!

Comment: @stevuu But what if there is no application module other then the default? (ng-app=""). Also this is not required for the built in services, so there must be a way to make it simple to use... Or not?

Comment: Built-in services are declared on the `ng` module, so possibly you could add them there with `angular.module("ng").service(...)`. But that sounds a bad idea!

Comment: Thank you :-) that is what I need. It would worth an answer so that I could accept - with implications clearly understood. Even if using TheirModule to include MyModule is the regular way, first time users (to angular or jaydata) have enough to learn on the first days without this particular bloat to be dealt with... the preferred way should be used after the first level of understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add components to the `ng` module, which is the default module, with `angular.module("ng").service(...)`. As mentioned in the comments, this is a bad idea for several reasons, most prominently that the Angular team might provide a service with the same name later.

For reference, the preferred way is to define your own module such as `myAwesomeDataModule` and add it as a dependency in other modules: `angular.module("myModule", ["myAwesomeDataModule"])`.

Comment: BTW - using the module chain it is also possible that you just pick the same service name someone else picked - so it will not save you from being shadowed occasionally.

Comment: If naming conflict is the most prominent reason for not attaching services to ng module then the solution is simple, namespacing. E.g. angular.module("ng").service("MyCompany.Module.AwesomeApp.Service.UserAuthentication", ...). AngularJS does not natively support post-bootstrap module injection yet so attaching services on the ng module allows for easy injection without hacks when using AMD libraries like RequireJS.